# Creating a list from ansible command module results

Tags: ansible

I'm using 'command' ansible module in a loop with multiple items to execute a command that returns JSON result, and I'm registering it, thus creating multiple results.

```
- name: Create a target groups
  command: >
    aws elbv2 create-target-group --name {{ item.key }} --protocol TCP --port {{ item.value.port }} --vpc-id {{ vpc_facts.vpc.id }}
  register: elbv2_target_groups
  with_dict: "{{ apis }}"
```

Now I'm not sure how to map results over specific attribute to create a list. I can extract this attribute from a single result :

`(elbv2_target_groups.results.0.stdout|from_json).TargetGroups.0.TargetGroupArn`

But how do I do it over multiple results to create a list, something like :

`(elbv2_target_groups.results.stdout|from_json)|map(attribute='TargetGroups.0.TargetGroupArn')|list`

Full output of 'elbv2_target_groups' https://pastebin.com/u64fdesc

Answer (score 0):

Do it step by step:

1. Make a list of `stdout`'s: `elbv2_target_groups.results | map(attribute='stdout') ...`
2. Apply `from_json` filter to each element: `... | map('from_json') ...`
3. Extract required value: `... | map(attribute='TargetGroups.0.TargetGroupArn') ...`
4. Convert to list: `... | list`.

Like this: `elbv2_target_groups.results | map(attribute='stdout') | map('from_json') | map(attribute='TargetGroups.0.TargetGroupArn') | list`.